# Facebook content sharing

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a simple code that I can't get to work. My website is `asaphot.com` and I have different images based on id and the url sample is `http://asaphot.com/photos/14`. Now my codes are:

```
<meta property="og:url"           content="http://asaphot.com/photos/14" />
    <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
    <meta property="og:title"         content="ASAPHOT" />
    <meta property="og:description"   content="Asaphot image" />
    <meta property="og:image"         content="{{ baseUrl() }}/assets/uploads/test.jpg" />

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=696480183784974";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://asaphot.com/photos/14" data-layout="button_count"></div>
```

Whenever I click share, I only get the Canonical Url which is `http://asaphot.com/login` but Fetched Url is `http://asaphot.com/photos/14`.

The homepage shows up when I click share:
[image]

Am I missing something here?

Comment: can you to this page without login?? `http://asaphot.com/photos/14`,

Comment: @NiranjanNRajumm you should login first

Comment: facebook can't login, you need to share public URLs

Comment: Oh yea I see! Thank you. I will try.

Comment: Guys, still the same even if it doesnt require login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to login to go that page.

When facebook is parses your URL, its encountering login page. So its going to login.

**Solution:**

Url Shared to facebook should not have any login.

Keep things to be shared without login.

**EDIT**
I dont think ots safe to do this,

But you can try this,

```
$host = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
if (substr($host, (strlen($host)-13)) == 'facebook.com' ){
    //set a variable in session.or set login
}
```

Comment: Its because, you content is in facebook cache,

Comment: go to that url, and enter your url to share, it will show the updated data.

Comment: did it, still the same

Comment: what is the url you are trying to share??

Comment: Glad it helped you:).Consider accepting answer if it was helpful.

Comment: I have a question, is there a way to check that only facebook.com is allowed to access the url without logging in?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95652/discussion-between-niranjan-n-raju-and-fewflyby).

Comment: `gethostbyaddr` is costly, you rather don’t want to do that on every request. You can [identify the FB scraper by its User Agent](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#scraperinfo) - but keep in mind, everyone can “fake” that, so people might be able to see your content even if they are not logged in, if you implement an exception for the FB scraper.

Comment: However, I agree with what was already said before – it doesn’t make the most sense to share stuff on FB, that is protected behind a login. If I see such a link in my news feed, only to be asked to login on a site that I know nothing about when I click on it – that is a frustrating user experience. So unless your shares are addressing a limited audience only (like they get posted in a group, where every member is a user of your website as well), it is not the best idea to share such login-protected URLs to begin with.

Comment: Thats why i have even mentioned that `its not safe`